# Rename csv header using bash script

Tags: bash, sed, header

I want to rename the header of a csv file using bash script. Original csv file header looks like below:

```
temp.csv
    ,id,too,Issue,Valid,DPT,RH,TMP,U,V
    1,1,22383,2015-01-15 00:00:00 GMT,2015-01-15 00:00:00 GMT,269.8000183,80.90000153,272.6300049,3.039999962,-0.560000002
    1

            id  to  Issue   Valid   DPT RH  TMP U   V
      1     2    3  4        5      6   7    8  9   10

I
```

want to rename column header as below:

```
 Cell   id  too Issue   Valid   DPT RH  TMP U   V
    1   2    3  4        5      6   7   8  9   10
```

Comment: Are the columns separated by spaces or tabs?

Comment: My bad. Columns separated by **,**.

Comment: echo new header, then use `tail -n +2` to output original csv file from the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` replace the header or the first line:

```
new_header=" Cell   id  too Issue   Valid   DPT RH  TMP U   V"
sed -i '' "1s/.*/$new_header/" file
```

This assumes that you don't have the `sed` expression separator `/` in your new header. In case you do, use a different separator in the `sed` expression.

Comment: Thanks. Will this work when my columns are separated by `,`? I am working first time on bash script. My questions might sound stupid.

Comment: `,` shouldn't be an issue.  However, `;` can be.

Comment: @codeforester, I am getting error `./BASH.SH: line 2: $'\r': command not found` while running this code `new_header="Cell,id,too,Issue,Valid,DPT,RH,TMP,U,V"
sed -i '' "1s/.*/$new_header/" temp.csv`.  Any comments?

Comment: Windows 8, I am using.

Comment: And my file looks like this `,id,too,Issue,Valid,DPT,RH,TMP,U,V
1,1,22383,2015-01-15 00:00:00 GMT,2015-01-15 00:00:00 GMT,269.8000183,80.90000153,272.6300049,3.039999962,-0.560000002
1`.

Comment: I think there are trailing carriage returns in your script.  Remove them with dos2unix command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160139/discussion-between-kaushik-and-codeforester).

Comment: @codeforester, it shows `$ cat -A bash.sh 
#!/bin/bash$ 
$ 
new_header="cell id too issue valid DPT RH TMP U V"$ 
sed -i '' "1s/.*/$new_header/" temp.csv`.

Comment: Thank you so much @codeforester. It's finally working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the first line with a different line. `sed` can do it for you:

```
sed -i -e "1 { r"<(echo ' Cell   id  too Issue   Valid   DPT RH  TMP U   V')"
d
}" file
```

To expand on the command

- `-i` edits the file in place (you can skip this)
- `-e` following is a sed command
- `1` execute the commands in the `{}` when you see the first line of input
- `r` inserts the text from the following "file"
- `<( echo ' ... ')` produces the new header on standard output, and assigns it to a file that is then readable by the sed command (`r` will insert that text)
- `d` deletes the line

So, insert a new line of text and delete the old one.

If you do not need to edit the file in place, easier to do:

```
(
  echo ' Cell   id  too Issue   Valid   DPT RH  TMP U   V'
  tail -n +2 file
) > file.new
```

Comment: Thanks @chutz!. But When I am running this command I am getting the following error `sed: cannot rename ./sedTKtPM3: Device or resource busy`. How to resolve this?

Comment: @Kaushik, could be permissions.